# How to display a pretty error with apollo link error

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, apollo, react-apollo

I've a problem with apollo-link-error, I'm able to log the error but I would like show a modal with the error or display it on another page, is it possible without handling the error on each request ?

React, Apollo-client/server, https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/tree/feature/apollo-pure

```js
    onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError, response  }) => {
      console.log(graphQLErrors);
      if (graphQLErrors) {
        graphQLErrors.map(({message, locations, path, extensions}) => {
          console.warn(
            `[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, Location: ${locations}, Path: ${path}`,
          );
          if (extensions && extensions.exception && (extensions.exception.code === 16 || extensions.code === 'UNAUTHENTICATED')) {
            // UNAUTHENTICATED
            response.errors = null;
            history.push('/login');
          }
        });
      }
      if (networkError) console.warn(`[Network error]: ${networkError}`);
    }),
```

For now, I can catch the error with an error boundary if it's happening while rendering and show it a pretty way. But when the error occurs after rendering, it's ignored